# ASP.NET Core custom client certificate validation not called

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, client-certificates

I'm trying to implement custom client certificate validation for an integration test setup. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1.latest and Kestrel like so:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel(
    ok => ok.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(
      o =>
      {
        o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
        o.ClientCertificateValidation = RememberClientCertificate;
      }))
  [..]
  .UseUrls("https://localhost:5051")

[..]

private static bool RememberClientCertificate (X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  LastClientCertificate = clientCertificate;
  return true;
}
```

However, my function RememberClientCertificate is never ever called. Regardless of whether I'm sending a client certificate or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: the client certificate is not trusted by the server, it is self-signed (trusting the certificate doesn't seem to work either though)

Comment: Could u reach any progress on this problem?

Comment: Yes, it turned out, I was indeed not sending a client certificate. Our client had a flaw...

Comment: After your comment i double checked and i see the same: ClientCertificate is not set in the Header. On any chance: Do u send the request also from C#?

Comment: We used PowerShell and it has been a script-block-does-not-have-access-to-outer-variables-without-passing-them-in problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. The method that validate the client certificate is not execute. could someone solve the problem? Thanks.